# ICMP types commands on CMD?

Tags: icmp

To use ICMP type 8 we write :

```
>ping IP@.
```

I was wondering what commands would allow me to use other types of ICMP like type 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You mention "CMD", so I'm going to answer this under the assumption that you are talking about DOS/Windows.)

The `ping` command in Windows only sends Type 8 (Echo Request). If you want to send other types, you'll need a third-party utility.

Comment: I'll be thankful if you suggest me a third-party utility for windows

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here. You can try at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.